# How to read value from config file (groovy script) in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, config, jenkins-groovy

I want to read some value(ex. user Login info) from config file in Jenkins pipeline script.

downloaded plugin "Config File Provider Plugin(ver.3.10.0)"

and i create config file.
[image]

I want to read that user info (line 2)
[image]

anyone have ideas ?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use the `Config File Provider` with a Groovy script. First, you have to load it to your pipeline and then execute it. So for that, you have to restructure your Groovy script as well. Please check the below.

**Jenkins Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('ConfigTest') {
                
            steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '078d4943-231c-4156-9b88-8334cd8a9402', variable: 'GroovyScript')]) {

                    echo " =========== Reading Groovy Script"
                    script {
                        def script = load("$GroovyScript")
                        script.setProperties()
                        echo "${USER_ID}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of the Script**

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def USER_ID;
  
def setProperties() {
    USER_ID = "abcd@gmail.com"
}

return this
```